# How to test Laravel echo server websockets in Postman

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-websockets

I entered wss://echo-dev.***.de as url and selected Socket.IO type and version 2 for client version. Also added Bearer {token} in the headers section.
But still cannot receive any message.